# 100% div (over browser) in boxed div

Tags: css

i want to create an div that is 100% (of Browser). The following div is in a div that ist not full width container (that container must stand)
I try this:

```
<div class="container">

<div style="
width: 100%;
padding-left: 1000px;
padding-right: 1000px;
margin: 0 -1000px;
background-color: #075283;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;">

TEXT

</div>

</div>
```

but i have scroller in browser.
how can i fix it that the browser and the smartphone show me only the full lenght of the div in the lenght of the browser?

Comment: You want a DIV, which is in a container, to be the size of the browser window, when the parent is a smaller size?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8m0g678f/

Comment: look at this please: http://mediaclusive.de/main.html

Comment: and i want that when i go to smartphone view that the blue container is only viewable in the width of the browser

Comment: Try height: 100vh same as this jsfiddle.net/8m0g678f

Comment: the problem is in width not in height

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd need the div that has to be 100%, be inside another smaller div, but you could always do something like.

```
.inner-div {
  position: absolute; // Or fixed if the parent div has position: relative or absolute.
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: i must insert a div that is 100% relative not absoulte that is my problem

Comment: What do you mean? Why does it matter if it's relative in this case?

Comment: I did, and after removing all random paddings and margins, and applying the styles I mentioned above, it works as you wanted.

Comment: when i remove all padding and margins the blue div is in the class container and not over 100%

Comment: u are right but the container must be a relative position

Comment: So, as my comment in the code said, instead of making it `position: absolute`, make it `position: fixed`.

Comment: then its not relative and i have other divs before and after this code

Comment: I mean make the child div `position: fixed` and the container `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; float:left;">

<div style="
width: 100%;
float:left;
background-color: #075283;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;">

TEXT

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [viewportwidth/viewportheight (vw/vh)](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)!

```
.wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    width:500px;
    background:red;
}

.inner {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: blue;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[Working example on jsfiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/825e4ws1/)